# Building a dependencies jar with Maven

Tags: maven

Currently our maven build includes all the dependencies in the jar, using `jar-with-dependencies`.

We want to split this into two separate jars, one with the project application code and files, and one with the dependencies.

How is this done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is done using the maven Assembly plugin

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

Comment: Which is the goal to use in place of jar-with-dependencies ?

Comment: There is only one - assembly:single. However, what this goal does is dependent on how you configure your assembly.xml

Answer (score 0):

Use the maven-shade-plugin instead with following configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-libs</finalName>
    <artifactSet>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </artifactSet>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

The trick is to define a specific final name. This avoids the replacement of the default jar, which is packaged by the maven-jar-plugin. The default name is **${project.artifactId}-${project.version}**. So simply add a suffix like **libs**. Then exclude the artifact itself, because the classes should not be packaged twice.

The build will result in two jar files:

1. **${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar**, containing the classes and files of the project
2. **${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-libs.jar**, containing the content of all the dependencies